# unsemantic responsive columns - won't resize on tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, unsemantic-css

I am using the **unsemantic** grid layout, however, with the following code I expect the **body** div to resize to 100% when the resolution lies within the tablet range:

```
<div class="grid-parent tablet-grid-100 grid-80" id="body">
    <div class="grid-100" id="search-result">
        search return
    </div>  
    <div class="grid-50" id="column-left">Column left</div>
    <div class="grid-50" id="column-right">Column right</div>
</div>
```

However, it remains at 80% until it reaches mobile size (where it defaults back to 100%). I have included the following css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/dan.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-responsive-tablet.css" />
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-mobile.css" />
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
        path: './assets/stylesheets/',
        dynamic: true,
        range: [
          '0 to 767px = unsemantic-grid-mobile.css',
          '767px = unsemantic-grid-desktop.css'
        ]
      };
    </script>
    <script src="./assets/javascripts/adapt.min.js"></script>
```

I really can't see why it's not working!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain and not answer your questions, but why not just include your mobile and desktop CSS into a single file and utilise the @media function to apply them. This avoids having to load in another JS file and run scripts which more than makes up for the small increase in file size.

Answer (score 0):

it seems u have to call unsemantic-grid-tablet.css via adapt, not call unsemantic-grid-responsive-tablet.css via link. Try this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/dan.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-base.css" />
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-mobile.css" />
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
        path: './assets/stylesheets/',
        dynamic: true,
        range: [
          '0 to 767px = unsemantic-grid-mobile.css',
          '767px to 1025px = unsemantic-grid-tablet.css',
          '1025px = unsemantic-grid-desktop.css'
        ]
      };
    </script>
    <script src="./assets/javascripts/adapt.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use **Unsemantic** with **Adapt.js** for your use-case with tablet breakpoints:

- Load only the base CSS initially.
- If JavaScript is disabled or unavailable, then load the responsive CSS with tablet breakpoints.
- Configure and load Adept.js in the head of your HTML document.
- If you only want to utilize 80% width for the desktop default (grid-80), then you may also want to take advantage of prefix-10 to keep your layout centered.

I was able to successfully test the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/dan.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-base.css">
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/unsemantic-grid-responsive-tablet.css">
</noscript>
<script>
    var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
        path: './assets/stylesheets/',
        dynamic: true,
        range: [
            '0 to 767px = unsemantic-grid-mobile.css',
            '767px to 1025px = unsemantic-grid-tablet.css',
            '1025px = unsemantic-grid-desktop.css'
        ]
    };
</script>
<script src="./assets/javascripts/adapt.min.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<div class="grid-parent grid-80 prefix-10 tablet-grid-100" id="body">
    <div class="grid-100" id="search-result">
        search return
    </div>  
    <div class="grid-50" id="column-left">column left</div>
    <div class="grid-50" id="column-right">column right</div>
</div>
```